# How to add User info from DB to "inMemoryAuthentication"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Because I want to build an REST API which use session id as token so I looking an example for spring security, in that case they hard code to set user info to memory authentication.

```
 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("testt").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

So how to set the user info from DB which have the same name with login userName that supplied by client to inMemoryAuthentication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations) interface is what you are looking for, though it doesn't get used in conjunction with in-memory authentication.

- *In-memory Authentication*: User specifies the usernames and passwords, and they are stored in-memory only
- *Custom UserDetailsService*: User specifies the way to obtain usernames and passwords

To supply your own `UserDetailsService`, you can simply expose it as a bean (no need to use the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`)

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return username -> {
        MyUser myUser = this.myUserRespository.findByUsername(username);
        return new MyUserDetails(myUser);
    };
}
```

Note that a `UserDetailsService` returns a `UserDetails` instance, which is a Spring Security interface. So, it's recommended you also build a simple bridge object that extends whatever your domain object is for your user:

```
private static class MyUserDetails extends MyUser implements UserDetails {
    public MyUserDetails(MyUser myUser) {
        super(myUser);
    }

    // ... implement UserDetails methods

}
```

Comment: Thank for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) interface and you also require some entity classes like User and Authority.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        /* auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("chief").password("{noop}chief")
                .roles("CHIEF"); 
        */
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

[Example](https://github.com/pathak-gaurav/british-transport-police/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gaurav/securelogin/configuration/SecurityConfig.java)

Comment: I'd recommend an adjustment here. In-memory authentication provides its own user details service, with the users you've supplied. To ask Spring Security to register a user details service (via `inMemoryAuthentication()`) and to supply another (via `userDetailsService(userDetailsService)`) is duplicative.

Comment: @jzheaux I must agree with you on that. +1 for your answer.